# Python Package Error After Upgrading Ubuntu From 18.04 To 20.04

Tags: 20.04, dependencies, do-release-upgrade, python-2.7

I have upgraded my Ubuntu Server OS to 20.04 from 18.04 with this command "sudo do-release-upgrade".
While upgrading, there was some problems with downloading packages for network problem.
Anyhow, my server has been upgraded.

But after upgrading OS, there was some critical errors while upgrading packages.
For some reason, python 2 packages are broken.

The errors are below.

```
root@myserver:~# apt upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-asn1crypto : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                     Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-bs4 : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
              Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-cairo : Depends: python (< 2.8)
                Depends: python (>= 2.7~)
                Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-certifi : Depends: python (< 2.8)
                  Depends: python (>= 2.7)
                  Depends: python:any (>= 2.6.6-7~)
 python-cffi-backend : Depends: python (< 2.8)
                       Depends: python (>= 2.7~)
                       Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                       Depends: python:any (>= 2.7~)
 python-chardet : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                  Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-crypto : Depends: python (< 2.8)
                 Depends: python (>= 2.7~)
                 Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                 Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-cryptography : Depends: python (< 2.8)
                       Depends: python (>= 2.7~)
                       Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                       Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-dbus : Depends: python (< 2.8)
               Depends: python (>= 2.7~)
               Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
               Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
               Recommends: python-gi but it is not installed
 python-dnspython : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                    Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-enum34 : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                 Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-gobject-2 : Depends: python (< 2.8)
                    Depends: python (>= 2.7~)
                    Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                    Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-greenlet : Depends: python (< 2.8)
                   Depends: python (>= 2.7~)
                   Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                   Depends: python:any (>= 2.7~)
 python-html5lib : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                   Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-idna : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
               Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-ipaddress : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                    Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-lockfile : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                   Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-lxml : Depends: python (< 2.8)
               Depends: python (>= 2.7~)
               Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
               Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-olefile : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                  Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-openssl : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                  Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-passlib : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                  Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-pil : Depends: python (< 2.8)
              Depends: python (>= 2.7~)
              Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
              Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-pkg-resources : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                        Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-psutil : Depends: python (< 2.8)
                 Depends: python (>= 2.7~)
                 Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                 Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-pyasn1 : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                 Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-pyasn1-modules : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                         Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-reconfigure : Depends: python (>= 2.6)
 python-requests : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                   Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-six : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
              Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-support : Depends: python (>= 2.5)
                  Depends: python-minimal but it is not installable
 python-urllib3 : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                  Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-webencodings : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                       Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python2-minimal : Depends: python2.7-minimal (>= 2.7.17~rc1-1~) but it is not installed
                   Recommends: python2 but it is not installed
 ubuntu-minimal : Depends: sudo
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

In now, I can't run "sudo" command with non root user.

```
Command 'sudo' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install sudo       # version 1.8.31-1ubuntu1.2, or
apt install sudo-ldap  # version 1.8.31-1ubuntu1.2
```

So I have tried the command "apt install sudo" with root user, but same errors are shown.
I have tried dpkg recoveration from advanced boot menu, but nothing changes.
In my opinion, there was any problems with python packages.
Please help me.

Comment: Seems like you encountered more problems than a mere "network problem". Were it my system, I would backup the data and then reinstall Ubuntu. I could probably fix the package issue -- I'm experienced at troubleshooting those. But that's not the point. The point is that *you don't know what other problems are lurking from your botched upgrade*. You could likely find out from reviewing your logs...but if you don't know how to do that, or don't want to invest the necessary time, then a reinstall is a reliable and simple alternative.

Comment: There are many important services and data on my server. So, I wanna to repair system without reinstalling the OS. What logs are useful for me? Please help me in detail.

Comment: Start with the logs in /var/log/dist-upgrades. There is no step-by-step tutorial -- this is an experience we all had, we all learned from, grew new skills from. The key skills are the patience to read --line-by-line-- logs and error messages, to be able to Search/lookup those messages that you don't understand, and thereby to filter out the unusual events from the routine. Then you put on your detective hat and reconstruct the difference between what should have happened and what actually happened, and look for the reason. Then you fix that reason. Developers WANT you to read error messages.